# CSS - Overlay image display's in chrome and opera but doesn't display in firefox

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, firefox, overlay

I have this image that i have displayed over slider in my Wordpress page. 
It worked fine until i changed layout :/

I have no idea why but now i can see that image only in chrome and opera. 
I tested it in firefox and IE(ugh) too and it doesn't work in those!
Didn't change the code at all. It's as it was on older layout, but somehow it no longer works.

---

Both slider and image are in same widget area. Image with class is in text widget.

**edit:** tested it now on twenty twelve theme has same problem but in twenty eleven theme it works like it should.

```
#text-widget-4 {
    background-color: transparent; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    margin: -50px !important;
    padding: 0px;
} 

.slider-overlay {
    position: absolute;  
    top: 120px;  
    left: 50px; 
    z-index:10; 
    border: none !important;
}

.meteor-slides-widget {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

---

This is what i see from firebug.

```
<div class="row">
 <header id="required-header" class="twelve columns required-header" role="banner">
  <aside id="meteor-slides-widget-1" class="widget meteor-slides-widget">
    <div id="meteor-slideshowheader" class="meteor-slides header 
      navnone { next: '#meteor-      nextheader', prev: '#meteor-prevheader',
      pager: '#meteor-buttonsheader' }" >
    </div>
  </aside>

  <aside id="text-4" class="widget widget_text">
     <div class="textwidget">
         <img class="slider-overlay" src="http://postimage.org/blahblah/image.png"/>
     </div>
  </aside>
       --couple more elements here: navigation and search form - not important--
 </header>
</div>
```

I would like to avoid posting code as it is on server (aka not from firebug) because it's spread through different files, as in plural. If someone wants i can give link to the site through private message.

---

Thank you in advance.

---

**EDIT! IT'S FIXED!!**

Thank you very much!!

This is how it went: 
I switched text-widget to relative and whole content went up ignoring all elements above it. I kept it and then i added another div before `<div class="row">` and then it just needed some moving around with margins and padding.

Comment: I need to see this in action before I can help you.

Comment: You should really format your CSS properly.

Comment: Not enough code here to reproduce the problem.

Comment: um... what else do you need?
Sorry i through that if i say it's in Wordpress it should be enough to just put those two in any wordpress widget area to test.

Comment: um "tested it now on twenty twelve theme and it works same but in twenty eleven theme it has no problems." so neither one has issues?

Comment: twenty twelve has problems.
twenty eleven doesn't. sorry, right that sentence up there didn't make sense, edited :P

Comment: Not downvoting because you are new (although, don't be afraid to get downvoted: you have 1 rep, downvote wont send you subzero :) Chillax!)

As for the question, If you could post some of the html here, it would help a lot.

Comment: @Harsh thank you, hope this bit of html is enough... i'm not sure if i can wrap my head around all the files it's spread into in my theme x_x
And only thing i'm afraid in down-voting is that i won't get answer ;_;

Comment: As long as you are willing to improve your questions, the probability of getting "one" answer remains high :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#text-widget-4 {
  position: absolute; <!-- try making this relative
  top: 0px; 
} 

.slider-overlay {
  position: absolute;  <!-- so that this can be positioned correctly
}
```

**Perhaps**, `#text-widget-4` is getting hidden behind the `meteor-slides-widget`, due to it's position absolute.

I'm not pretty sure about this, but give it a try nonetheless.

Comment: That sort of worked xD
It made content of the page go up on the page and behind slider.

Then i sort of got pissed and added another div just around the two elements and moved it around a bit with css.
Now it's anoying my ocd if i look in code but works!
Maybe the problem was working with other elements in header area?

Comment: I would not be able to tell you with any level of confidence what would be wrong there, but good to see it solved :) And revisit the problem later with a fresh mind, maybe you'll see what was wrong.